# How to debug Ember addon with breakpoints in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ember.js, ember-addon

Am trying to get breakpoints to work in VS Code with an Ember addon (version 3.18).  Have tried launch.json as:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "edge",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
        "port": 9222,
        "runtimeArgs": [ "--remote-debugging-port=9222" ],
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "dummy/*": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/dummy/app/*",
            "test-addon/*": "${workspaceFolder}/addon/*",
        }
    }
]}
```

It works fine for setting breakpoints in files in the dummy test app.  But when setting a breakpoint in files within the addon folder, VSCode says "Breakpoint set but not yet bound".  How can this be fixed? I assume the 2nd sourcemap path override is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of further experimenting, seems the 2nd path should be:

`"addon-tree-output/test-addon/*": "${workspaceFolder}/addon/*"`

**Update:**

Turns out this still doesn't break inside addon files correctly.  eg. in an addon component file:

```
@action
click() {
   console.log('hello')  // Set breakpoint here
}
// Instead, jumps to here
```

Some difference between the dummy and vendor source maps perhaps? There is an option in ember-cli-build.js:

```
babel: {
  sourceMaps: 'inline'
}
```

but this only applies to the dummy test app as it states in the comment underneath it?